# Remote lookup EJB deployed on JBoss from Websphere

Tags: jboss, websphere, lookup

I have deployed EJB on JBoss and I want to look it up from Websphere. I use maven to manage my project. This the code that I use to lookup the EJB

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://192.168.0.11:4447");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass");
props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
return (IEjbInterface) ctx.lookup("my-ear/my-app/MyClass!my.class.interfaces.IEjbInterface");
```

I have added the following dependencies for the lookup

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-naming</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This code works from a standalone application, but when wrapped in WAR which is deployed on Websphere the lookup throws the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.BrokenPipeException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bom jboss-as-ejb-client-bom 7.1.1.Final contains the org.jboss.xnio library, but it is version 3.0.3.GA. The 7.2.0.Final bom references newer version of xnio (3.0.7.GA) and it works fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

From the ClassNotFoundException I think you need to create a dependency on the org.jboss.xnio module. For further info see: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7?_sscc=t